# Maven: how to not depend on Parent POM

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-3

I have a Maven multi-module project. Something like this:

```
- ParentProject
   - ChildA
   - ChildB
   - ChildC
```

The child projects inherit from a Parent POM (`ParentProject`) solely for the reason of sharing stuff like `<build>`, `<scm>` and `<properties>`, so as to not repeat it in all the child modules. Thus, the objective of the parent-child relationship is not related to dependencies in any way. It plays a role at build-time, not at runtime, so to speak.

The child projects's artifacts are for consumption for a wider audience, hence they'll be published into a centralized repo.

How do I "break" the relationship between from the child up to the parent seen from a perspective of a consumer of a child?

Let's say another project, `ProjectX`, adds a dependency on `ChildA`. When doing this the Maven client will attempt to not only download the POM and artifact of `ChildA` itself but will even try to download the POM for `ParentProject`. However, there's absolutely no need for that POM seen from a consumer point of view. It doesn't contain information that the consumer needs to know.

How can I break this relationship from consumer's perspective? Forcing the POM for `ParentProject` to be published into a repo seems pointless as nobody has any need for it there.

Perhaps there's another way that Maven will let me share things like build instructions and properties between projects without mandating that a Parent POM exists in a centralized repo ?

Or perhaps there's some way I can manipulate the POM for the Child projects which gets put into the centralized repo (removing the `<parent>` element as it is irrelevant).

Perhaps only me but I feel that Maven is conflating two unrelated concepts here (build-time vs consume-time) and forcing unnecessary roundtrips and unnecessary artifacts in repo. I haven't dabbled with Gradle yet but I wonder if it does it any better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the Maven POM is both build POM and consumer POM. This is not ideal, and will probably change in future versions of Maven.

At the moment, your best option seems to be the flatten Maven plugin, which allows you to remove "unnecessary" parts of the POM before uploading it.

Comment: Thx. I think the [Maven Flatten Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/) is exactly what I need. It seems others have had issues with this "design flaw" of Maven.  :-)

Comment: 1 hour later: Works great. To correct my previous comment the plugin's correct name is *Flatten Maven Plugin*  (not Maven Flatten Plugin) as this is _not_ an official plugin.

Comment: And I see there might be an official solution for this problem (I've come to learn it is known as the "build vs consumer POM") in Maven 4.0. Discussed and explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDAmlNKZJto&feature=youtu.be). Great to see Maven moving forward.